# probability of DNS spoofing (Kaminsky attack)

Tags: security, dns, udp

Assuming that "i" is spoofed packets sent by attacker before the legitimate response from the legitimate DNS server received. Transaction ID in all DNS queries is randomized, but the UDP source port is fixed.

I am wondering what would be probability of DNS poisoning in the first iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the probability of attack would be the  the number of spoofed packets/maximum range for your transaction id.